Can i use one shared-worker across sub domains?
I am having 4 react web applications, all of them use realtime data from webscockets.
Currently in each of them i create a web worker and that handles all the websocket things,
It's a stock broking type app, so we recive prices of stocks in real time and other data too.
all of them are deployed of different sub domains.
I saw the concept of shared worker. I tried to implement that here.
My goal was to use one websocket connection with shared worker, which can be used by all the web apps open.
This was working, if i host my application on a same subdomian,
I tried various solutions uisng chatgpt, but dose't work,
I hosted the my worker file at a subdomian and was accessing that in all my applications
but i wanted to check if this can work even when the applications are deployed in different subdomian
If anyone has any idea around it
